# Set static ip if not obtained from DHCP (script)

Tags: linux, ip, dhcp, ifconfig

I work on embedded device with linux on it. I want to use DHCP client first, but if there will be no answer from DHCP Server I want to set static-default IP. I suppose it shouldn't be complicated, but I haven't found strict answer.

I'm thinking about 2 solutions (Unfortunately I can test them in few days):

1. I set static IP with ifconfig, then I call udhcpc. If udhcpc will not obtain new IP, old one will stay.
2. I can also first call udhcpc, wait a while and check if IP is obtained. But this is not nice for me. I wouldn't like to add any wait routines into startup.

BR
Bartek

I use udhcpc - something like:

```
udhcpc -n -f -i eth0 
if ifconfig | grep -A1 eth0 | grep inet 
    then
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

dhclient should support fallback via lease declaration
have a look at the `dhclient.conf` man page.

Add something like this to your `dhclient.conf`

```
timeout 10;
lease {
interface "eth0";
fixed-address 10.0.0.10;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
renew 2 2022/1/1 00:00:01;
rebind 2 2022/1/1 00:00:01;
expire 2 2022/1/1 0:00:01;
}
```

or you can assign a second IP to the interface like `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address 10.10.10.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: I use udhcpc and made something like:   udhcpc -n -f -i eth0 
  if ifconfig | grep -A1 eth0 | grep inet
  then

Comment: Why not also `auto eth0`?

Comment: @ygoe why not `auto <if>` causes the interface to be brought up automatically during boot, not manually by something like `ifup`. Consult the manual for details.

Comment: On linux4tegra I needed to add auto eth0 in order for it to ry dhcp when booting

Answer (score 0):

Although an old question, it might be worth noting here that Gentoo Linux has had this functionality for a long time (I've been using it since 2004).  Gentoo's network config file (/etc/conf.d/net) allows for fallback IP addresses to be easily specified for any interface in the event that DHCP fails, e.g.:

```
modules="dhclient"
config_eth0="dhcp"
config_eth1="dhcp"
dhclient_eth1="nogateway"
fallback_eth0="apipa"
fallback_eth1="192.168.10.10/24"
fallback_routes_eth1="default via 192.168.10.1"
```

The solution Maurizio provided to use an alias like eth0:0 is fine in many (probably most) situations, but not all.  I've run into one piece of software that does not consider eth0:0 to be a suitable substitute for eth0 when it is undefined due to no answer from DHCP, even though it is the same port.  So a static fallback address is slightly superior to the alias solution.