# Set saved static ip address if dhcp fails

Tags: linux, bash, networking, ip, dhcp

I'm trying to implement the following scene on a Raspberry Pi with wheezy in a bash script. I do that because I want a device always get a new IP if the DHCP is online, and at the same time I want it to keep the last used IP in the case the DHCP is offline. On top, IP address could change, and I have many many devices, so simply setup static IPs is not my choice:

> - Boot (not in the script ;) )
> - Switch on DHCP and try to get IP address
> - Check if I got one
>
> a) Got IP (DHCP successful)
>
> -> Save IP infos to file
>
> b) Didn't get IP (DHCP failed)
>
> -> Do nothing here
>
> - Set fixed IP address based on the information in the file

Now the point is that this works pretty awesome if I run the script manually, but if I let it run automatically after startup, the DHCP will fail **but will still give me an IP address**. Of course my script thinks that the DHCP got an ip address, but it's not the right one! 
sys.log tells me that:

```
dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
dhclient: Trying recorded lease 192.xxx.xx.xx
ifplugd(eth0)[1602]: client: Trying recorded lease 192.xxx.xx.xx
```

Now the question is:

- Can I deactivate the DHCP client service (I think it is ifplugd with dhclient) giving me that fake IP address?
- Or can I elsewise detect, that the DHCP request was not successful (and forfeit the fake address)?

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Switch off Ethernet >> log.log
ifconfig eth0 down
echo Set DHCP mode for Ethernet >> log.log
ifconfig eth0 up
dhclient -r eth0
dhclient eth0
echo Now check if we got ip address >> log.log
countLines=$(ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet addr" | wc -l)
if [ $countLines -ne 0 ]; then
  echo Found ip address via DHCP - Save it to ip.txt >> log.log
  ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet addr" > ip.txt
  echo Also save the resolv.conf - DNS settings >> log.log
  cp /etc/resolv.conf dns.txt
  #grep domain-name-servers /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases | tail -1 > dns.txt
else
  echo No new ip address - no DHCP online! Use the old settings instead... >> log.log
fi
echo Switch off DHCP - and release the current lease >> log.log
dhclient -r eth0
ipaddress=$(<ip.txt)
ipaddress=${ipaddress#*addr:}
ipaddress=${ipaddress% Bcast*}
broadcast=$(<ip.txt)
broadcast=${broadcast#*Bcast:}
broadcast=${broadcast% Mask*}
netmask=$(<ip.txt)
netmask=${netmask#*Mask:}
dnsserver=$(<dns.txt)
dnsserver=${dnsserver#*servers }
dnsserver=${dnsserver%;*}
echo Set static ip address now ip: $ipaddress, broadcast: $broadcast, netmask: $netmask... >> log.log
ifconfig eth0 $ipaddress broadcast $broadcast netmask $netmask
echo Set the nameserver >> log.log
cp dns.txt /etc/resolv.conf
```

It really puzzles me, that the script works out of the bash, but not after started automatically with system startup!

Comment: Have you looked at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727175/set-static-ip-if-not-obtained-from-dhcp-script ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok Mate,

Your problem is that your script believes that ifconfig will get no IP address if the DHCP is not found.

If dhclient fail to discover the DHCP server, `eth0` will get `169.254.*.*` address (self assigned)

You need to save what you got before run the dhclient.

Eg. `OLDIP=ifconfig eth0 | sed ... Inet ... #come with your SED statement`

Then you continue with:

```
dhclient eth0
If [$? !=0];then
    Ifconfig eth0 $OLDIP $OLDMASK
```

I'm writing from my phone so obviously the syntax is not correct.

Hope it helps